# MPI in conjunction with OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, mpi

While dividing my application in various tasks and convert it for a multi thread environment, I have realized that fundamentally I've got the base concept wrong: OpenCL is not suited for the kind of operations that I need to do in my app, but only for the mathematical part of the problem.

So at this point I was wondering if I could use MPI to fire up n threads on different devices, and then fire up OpenCL kernels if the device has a GPU.

Is this something that is commonly done, or using MPI exclude OCL and vice-versa?

My objective is to run an app on a computer and use any device attached to it (if present), to increase the computational power and share the task. The task itself is divided between crunching numbers (perfect for OCL), OGL render of the results coming from the data crunching part, UI management and interaction and data management (save, store, replace).

From what I understand MPI is not able to address threads to the GPU like OCL does, but OCL main use is math crunching, so it would not do any good if for example my app needs to access the network to retrieve information, or if it needs to use OGL to plot the results of a thread; in which case the best choice would be MPI.

Any suggestion about a viable option would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely doable (see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061419/any-advantage-of-mpicuda-over-just-pure-mpi/8064850#8064850)). All MPI really does is spawn multiple instances of your program and handle communication among them. It isn't concerned with what operations are performed locally on each individual node. For instance, at one point I've written an MPI program in which the main process used Qt to visualize the data it received from the workers.

Comment: Thanks for your message; checked the question linked and it has some good info. So if I've got this right, I can just make threads and send them out to the various devices, and the thread may call a function that calls a kernel to execute OCL code? I will probably write everything in C so it should work.

I am doing something similar to what you did; I am trying to use all that is connected via MPI, so I don't have to go crazy with threads order, and use the host to gather all the results and visualize them. I feel better knowing that it is doable :)

Comment: @newbiez: Something like that, yes, but the "make threads and send them out to the various devices" part makes me suspect you're not entirely clear on how MPI works. `mpiexec` starts processes, not threads, and each process is a completely new instance of your entire program. But yes, within those instances, you can start OCL threads that will use the local resources.

Comment: So I guess that I got it wrong then....my expectation was that I may divide my application in sub systems, and each one of them can be sent to a different unit (physical machine) and then the host coordinates everything. So to give a real case scenario, I would write the app so that the OGL part is done on one machine, the data is gathered on another, the calculations are distributed among 2 machines and the host coordinates everything, being sure that the OGL part is done only after that the calculations results are returned. Am I totally off track with MPI for my purpose?

Comment: @newbiez: No, that's still a perfect fit for MPI. However, there's no dedicated "host" machine in an MPI environment: all processes are equal apart from their rank, and they all start simultaneously on their respective machines (or rather, neither is guaranteed to start before the others). Typically, an MPI program will start by querying its own rank and using it to decide what role it plays. So you can still have a central control node if you want, but you'll have to coordinate things manually. Google a couple MPI example programs/tutorials, it'll all become clear. :)

Answer (score 5):

MPI and OpenMP is a quite standard hybrid programming model for HPC. There are no practical or theoretical limitations on doing the same with MPI and OpenCL.

MPI can handle the communication between processes while openCL handles the computationally intensive part on the GPUs.

In general, there are no limitations on using any library together with MPI as coordination language between a set of different processes on multiple machines as long as the environment is consistent (same OS, same library version, same architecture etc).

Comment: Thanks for your insight. The problem is that I need a non-consistent environment...I may hook up a pc, a mac or a droid device to the host, so I need something that is agnostic about where it runs...that's why I went for OCL. From what I know, MPI is also agnostic since it works on a level of abstraction, and does not care about specific details, but I cannot use it on GPUs; hence my attempt to use both.